# my logic for printing a loop isnt right. cant get my head aroud this

Tags: java

//The question itself (my code after that)

Variable n is randomly generated integer. Output characters '*' and '#' so that the first row contains only stars and the last one only number signs. The number of stars decreases in each consecutive row. The total number of characters in a row is n and there are n + 1 rows.

For example, if n has value 5, the program would output:

```
 *****  
 ****#    
 ***##      
 **###       
 *####      
 #####
```

//My code below!

```
Random r = new Random();       
int n = r.nextInt(5) + 10;    
System.out.println("n: "+n);

while(n>0){

for(int star = n; star>0; star--){
  System.out.print("*");
}

for(int hash = 0; hash<n; hash++){
  System.out.print("#");

    } 

    System.out.println("");  //new line
n--;


}
```

//My code output - problem: the #'s need to increase in size from 0 rather than decrease like the *'s

```
**********##########
*********#########
********########
*******#######
******######
*****#####
****####
***###
**##
*#
```

Comment: Looks like homework, but he's made a decent try of it. I'm willing to provide hints (though not all the code!).

Answer (score 1):

Just remember the line you are on. No need for algorithm talks.

```
final int n = 4; 

int lineNr = 0;

while (n >= lineNr)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= n - lineNr; i++)
        System.out.print("*");

    for (int j = 1; j <= lineNr; j++)
        System.out.print("#");

    System.out.println();
    lineNr++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're currently printing the correct number of `*`s on each iteration. The number of `#`s you should print is always equal to the iteration you're on (starting at 0). So you can keep a counter of this (say, `i`) which will be initialized to 0 and incremented once at the end of each `while`-loop iteration, and then you can print the `#`s by looping to `i`:

```
for (int hash = 0; hash < i; hash++) {
    System.out.print("#");
}
```

A better approach, however, would be to just use a `for`-loop in place of the `while`-loop and avoid changing `n`, keeping in mind that on the `ith` iteration you should print `n - i` `*`s and `i` `#`s:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

    for (int star = 0; star < n - i; star++) {  // n-i stars
        System.out.print("*");
    }

    for (int hash = 0; hash < i; hash++) {  // i hashes
        System.out.print("#");
    }

    System.out.println();  // don't need an empty string here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're starting okay with your `star` loop, but in your `hash` loop you're telling your program to just count back up to `n` and print that many hash marks.

Instead, you need another number to represent either the number of stars or the number of hashes; subtract from `n` to get the other number. Use a nested `for` loop; the outer one counts to `n` to print each row, and the inner one counts from 0 to `lineNumber` printing stars, then on up to `n` printing hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify n in the loop, because n gives you the total number of symbol for each line. Here I kept your program and introduced the variable i to use in the while loop.

```
Random r = new Random();       
int n = r.nextInt(5) + 10;    
System.out.println("n: "+n);
int i=n;

while(i>=0){

  for(int star = i; star>0; star--){
    System.out.print("*");
  }

  for(int hash = i; hash<n; hash++){
    System.out.print("#");
  } 

  System.out.println("");  //new line
  i--;
}
```

Comment: Your `while` condition is flawed. Firstly, it's `while(i>0)`, without `int`. Secondly, it's actually `while(i>=0)`, to print the last line. Other than that, it works.

Answer (score 0):

My code:

```
Random r = new Random();       
int lines = r.nextInt(5) + 10;
System.out.println("n: "+lines);

for (int n=lines; n>=0; n--) {
  String toPrint = "*";
  for(int i=0; i<lines; i++){
    if (i==n) {
      toPrint = "#";
    }
    System.out.print(toPrint);
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

I dislike your naming convention. Single letter chars are best left for loops alone. The main loop (in your case `while`) looks clearer as a simple `for`.

The check is done each time and this is perhaps less efficient than the two loops people here seem to use (just as you did). But IMO the code is much clearer to use. Notice the string switch is made only once per line.